# Basic interrogation about Spring boot and @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: spring-boot

I have a basic question about **Spring Boot:**

Say I am developping a **websocket app**. It seems the idea behind Spring Boot is as follows:

As a **developer** I am responsible for:

1. Including the following mvn dependency: `spring-boot-starter-websocket`
2. Annotate my configuration class with: `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

**Spring Boot** is then responsible for applying the following config: `WebSocketAutoConfiguration`

In a nutshell, is it how it works? Can someone please confirm of infirm the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

After adding *spring-boot-starter-websocket* to your configuration file and using the *@EnableAutoConfiguration* annotation, Spring will use you class path to automatically determine which configuration settings and beans need to be created for you.

Spring Boot will handle the *WebSocketAutoConfiguration* and any other necessary common configurations.

More information can be found here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: No problem. Yes, spring is an awesome Framework with some really great tools!

Comment: As of yesterday you also need to add `@EnableWebSocket` or `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` (the latter is probably better in most cases). The gs guide uses `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and the sample in Spring Boot uses `@EnableWebSocket`.